# Java Connect to a MySQL's sites DB

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I have a site with a MySql Database, and I would like to retrieve the information via a Java Program. The problem is that I'm not sure about how to do it. I have tried a few methods, but none works.
Long story short, I need help with the following :

- finding the IP of the server
- connecting to the database via IP
- creating a new connection with the details

I have tried the following :  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DOMAIN:3306/DB_NAME", "USER", "PASSWORD"); but doesn't work.

Thanks in advanced, and I apologize if the question is stupid, but I have no Java experience with DB's, and I can't understand how can a link between those 2 entities be established.

edit

The Class is the following

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/DB","USER", "PASS");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement             .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `categorii`");
            System.out.println( resultSet.getNString(3));
            } 
        catch (Exception M)
            {
            System.out.println(M.getMessage());
            }
}
```

}

An Exception is thrown which says : 
'Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.'

So it can't connect to the server, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had problems using this:

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DOMAIN:3306/DB_NAME", "USER", "PASSWORD");
```

Try this instead

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DOMAIN:3306/DB_NAME?user=USER&password=PASSWORD");
```

Comment: I had some troubles with the JDBC driver first, but managed to fixed it ... I found the SV IP  by pinging it, connected to it using the 3306 port, added my ip in the CPanel, so that connections from remote adresses would be allowed, but even after all this measures, the code won't work :| ... I will continue experimenting and researching tommorow, but I don't know what to do next... Thanks anyway for the answer :)

Comment: @user1777039 Maybe if you update your question with more details about your problem and you paste the **entire** code i can help you.